# Asp.Net MVC Still validating hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(":radio:eq(1)").click(function () {
        $("#JointApplicantInfo").show(1000);
    });

    $(":radio:eq(0)").click(function () {
        $("#JointApplicantInfo").hide(1000);
    });

});
```

to hide a div but when hidden the validations from

```
src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js">

src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">
```

are still happening even when hidden.

I am using [required] tags in the model to cause validation to happen.

I am unsure of how to make this not happen. I understand that it requires more scripting, but I am a novice and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Validation is independent of how a value is display, therefore it will always be validated if created as an input element.  Based on that, there is definitely a code smell of: why do you want a hidden element on the page that also has validation?

Comment: If it is not a mandatory field (hence you allow it to be hidden) then you should not decorate it with `[required]` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the jQuery validation and tell it to ignore hidden fields:

```
$(function() {
    var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    settings.ignore = ":not(:visible)";
});
```

[Reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/13/overriding-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-settings-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Edit: I should add though, as others have commented, it is not really correct to annotate a field as `[Required]` if it is only required under certain circumstances.

Comment: I don't necessarily have to put [required] in the model, but essentially when someone clicks "yes" the joint part of the app opens up and i want those fields to be validated when it's shown.

Comment: If you have the `[Required]` attribute, the server side validation will fail when you use `ModelState.IsValid`.